# Scala compiler not recognizing a view bound

Tags: scala

I've tried this line of code

```
def **[A <% Numeric[A]](l:List[A],m:List[A])=l.zip(m).map({t=>t._1*t._2})
```

However on compilation, I get this error

```
error: value * is not a member of type parameter A
def **[A <% Numeric[A]](l:List[A],m:List[A])=l.zip(m).map({t=>t._1*t._2})
```

When I look at the source for the Numeric trait, I see a `*` op defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instance of `Numeric` is not a number itself, but it is an object that offers operations to do the arithmetic. For example, an object `num` of type `Numeric[Int]` can add two integers like this: `num.plus(3, 5)` The result of this operation is the integer 7.

For integers, this is very trivial. However, for all basic numerical types, there is one *implicit* instance of `Numeric` available. And if you define your own numeric types, you can provide one.

Therefore, you should leave the bounds for `A` open and add an implicit parameter of type `Numeric[A]`, with which you do the calculations. Like this:

```
def **[A](l:List[A],m:List[A])(implicit num:Numeric[A])=l.zip(m).map({t=>num.times(t._1, t._2)})
```

Of course, `num.times(a,b)` looks less elegant than `a*b`. In most of the cases, one can live with that. However, you can wrap the value `a` in an object of type `Ops` that supports operators, like this:

```
// given are: num:Numeric[A], a:A and b:A
val a_ops = num.mkNumericOps(a)
val product = a_ops * b
```

Since the method `mkNumericOps` is declared `implicit`, you can also import it and use it implicitly:

```
// given are: num:Numeric[A], a:A and b:A
import num._
val product = a * b
```

Comment: Where would I put the import num._ statement in the context of my ** function?

Comment: You would need to open a block after the equals sign. I didn't test this, but I assume it would have to look like this: `def **[A](l:List[A],m:List[A])(implicit num:Numeric[A])={ import num._ ; l.zip(m).map({t=>t._1 * t._2}) }` -- I would try to go without it though; I'm unsure if the creation of the implicit wrapper Ops object affects performance, or if it will be optimized by the compiler.

Comment: I expect it should be optimized if escape analysis is enabled, but no guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve this with a [context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/context-and-view-bounds-again/4467012#4467012). Using the `context` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373070/how-do-i-get-an-instance-of-the-type-class-associated-with-a-context-bound/4373153#4373153), you can write:

```
def **[A : Numeric](l:List[A],m:List[A]) =
   l zip m map { t => context[A]().times(t._1, t._2) }
```

or

```
def **[A : Numeric](l:List[A],m:List[A]) = {
   val num = context[A]()
   import num._
   l zip m map { t => t._1 * t._2 }
}
```