# Why does Numeric behave differently than Ordered?

Tags: scala, typeclass

Scala has a number of traits that you can use as type classes, for example `Ordered` and `Numeric` in the package `scala.math`.

I can, for example, write a generic method using `Ordered` like this:

```
def f[T <% Ordered[T]](a: T, b: T) = if (a < b) a else b
```

I wanted to do a similar thing with `Numeric`, but this doesn't work:

```
def g[T <% Numeric[T]](a: T, b: T) = a * b
```

Why is there an apparent discrepancy between `Ordered` and `Numeric`?

I know there are other ways to do this, the following will work (uses a context bound):

```
def g[T : Numeric](a: T, b: T) = implicitly[Numeric[T]].times(a, b)
```

But that looks more complicated than just being able to use `*` to multiply two numbers. Why does the `Numeric` trait not include methods like `*`, while `Ordered` does include methods like `<`?

I know there's also `Ordering` which you can use in the same way as `Numeric`, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/context-and-view-bounds-again/4467012#4467012):

```
def f[A : Ordering](a: A, b: A) = implicitly[Ordering[A]].compare(a, b)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ordered` is just a few simple pimped methods that return either `Int` or `Boolean`, so no type-trickery is needed.

`Numeric`, on the other hand, has methods that return different types depending on the exact subclass used.  So while `Ordered` is little more than a marker trait, `Numeric` is a fully-featured type class.

To get your operators back, you can use `mkNumericOps` (defined in `Numeric`) on the lhs operand.

**UPDATE**

Miles is quite right, `mkNumericOps` is implicit, so just importing that instance of Numeric will give you back all the magic...

Answer (score 12):

The symbolic operators are available if you import them from the implicit Numeric[T]

```
def g[T : Numeric](a: T, b: T) = {
  val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  import num._
  a * b
}
```

This is clearly a bit unwieldy if you want to make use of just a single operator, but in non-trivial cases the overhead of the import isn't all that great.

Why are the operators not available without an explicit import? The usual considerations against making implicits visible by default apply here, perhaps more so because these operators are so widely used.

Answer (score 5):

You can reduce Miles' solution to only use 1 extra line by doing this:

Add an implicit conversion from `A : Numeric` to `Numeric[A]#Ops`

```
object Ops {
  implicit def numeric[A : Numeric](a: A) = implicitly[Numeric[A]].mkNumericOps(a)
}
```

Then bring this into scope in your method

```
def g[T : Numeric](a: T, b: T) = {
  import Ops.numeric
  a * b
}
```

See [Scala ticket 3538](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3538) for more info.