# How can I chain implicits in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicits

The pimp-my-library pattern allows me to seemingly add a method to a class by making available an implicit conversion from that class to one that implements the method.

Scala does not allow two such implicit conversions taking place, however, so I cannot got from `A` to `C` using an implicit `A` to `B` and another implicit `B` to `C`. Is there a way around this restriction?

Comment: @ryeguy [Here's a meta question for the pimp/enrich debate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184514/135887), because holy crap that tag.  *That tag*...

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Scala has a restriction on automatic conversions to add a method, which is that it won't apply more than one conversion in trying to find methods. For example:

```
class A(val n: Int)
class B(val m: Int, val n: Int)
class C(val m: Int, val n: Int, val o: Int) {
  def total = m + n + o
}

// This demonstrates implicit conversion chaining restrictions
object T1 { // to make it easy to test on REPL
  implicit def toA(n: Int): A = new A(n)
  implicit def aToB(a: A): B = new B(a.n, a.n)
  implicit def bToC(b: B): C = new C(b.m, b.n, b.m + b.n)

  // won't work
  println(5.total)
  println(new A(5).total)

  // works
  println(new B(5, 5).total)
  println(new C(5, 5, 10).total)
}
```

**EDIT: View bounds ('<%') are deprecated since Scala 2.11 https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629** (You can use type classes instead)

However, if an implicit definition requires an implicit parameter itself(View bound), Scala *will* look for additional implicit values for as long as needed. Continue from the last example:

```
// def m[A <% B](m: A) is the same thing as
// def m[A](m: A)(implicit ev: A => B)

object T2 {
  implicit def toA(n: Int): A = new A(n)
  implicit def aToB[A1 <% A](a: A1): B = new B(a.n, a.n)
  implicit def bToC[B1 <% B](b: B1): C = new C(b.m, b.n, b.m + b.n)

  // works
  println(5.total)
  println(new A(5).total)
  println(new B(5, 5).total)
  println(new C(5, 5, 10).total)
}
```

"Magic!", you might say. Not so. Here is how the compiler would translate each one:

```
object T1Translated {
  implicit def toA(n: Int): A = new A(n)
  implicit def aToB(a: A): B = new B(a.n, a.n)
  implicit def bToC(b: B): C = new C(b.m, b.n, b.m + b.n)

  // Scala won't do this
  println(bToC(aToB(toA(5))).total)
  println(bToC(aToB(new A(5))).total)

  // Just this
  println(bToC(new B(5, 5)).total)

  // No implicits required
  println(new C(5, 5, 10).total)
}

object T2Translated {
  implicit def toA(n: Int): A = new A(n)
  implicit def aToB[A1 <% A](a: A1): B = new B(a.n, a.n)
  implicit def bToC[B1 <% B](b: B1): C = new C(b.m, b.n, b.m + b.n)

  // Scala does this
  println(bToC(5)(x => aToB(x)(y => toA(y))).total)
  println(bToC(new A(5))(x => aToB(x)(identity)).total)      
  println(bToC(new B(5, 5))(identity).total)

  // no implicits required
  println(new C(5, 5, 10).total)
}
```

So, while `bToC` is being used as an implicit conversion, `aToB` and `toA` are being passed as *implicit parameters*, instead of being chained as implicit conversions.

**EDIT**

Related question of interest:

- [A discussion on types, origin and precedence of implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5598085/53013)

Comment: Nice explanation. The stated reason for disallowing implicit conversion chaining is to avoid complexity and debugging nightmare. I wonder why is then chaining  allowed for implicit parameters?

Comment: Nice! I learned something new. This should be on the "hidden features" page.

Comment: Thanks! One minor issue: I had to add add explicit result types to the functions `aToB` and `bToC` in `T2` when I tried it in REPL.

Comment: @Agl It won't be necessary on the upcoming 2.9, but I have modified the code to make it compatible with 2.8. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note that is the chaining you're trying to do involves higher kinded types, then again type inference can hose you.

I.e.   I  have M[A].  I have an implicit A=>B and an implicit M[_] => N[_], where both M and N are monadic.  I want to create an N[B] using the two conversions.  Chaining these requires an additional method call, the first to capture M[_] and the second to capture A.

Comment: @jsuereth Yeah, that can be tricky. I'll see if I can work out a reasonable short and understandable example.

Comment: @Peter Better to ask a question with that specific problem. I think adding it here would stray off topic.

Comment: Thanks @DanielC.Sobral! Terrific answer, really clarified things for me.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral That's a great answer! After reading it a few times, it doesn't look like crazy voodoo anymore.

Comment: Without view bounds:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html
(see comment in the bottom)

Answer (score 12):

Note that you can build circles with implicit parameters, too. Those are, however, detected by the compiler, as exhibited by this:

```
class Wrap {
  class A(implicit b : B)
  class B(implicit c : C)
  class C(implicit a : A)

  implicit def c = new C
  implicit def b = new B
  implicit def a = new A
}
```

The error(s) given to the user are not as clear as they could be, though; it just complains `could not find implicit value for parameter` for all three construction site. That might obscure the underlying problem in less obvious cases.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/mesagie/5132958) a code that also accumulates the path.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

// Vertices
case class A(l: List[Char])
case class B(l: List[Char])
case class C(l: List[Char])
case class D(l: List[Char])
case class E(l: List[Char])

// Edges
implicit def ad[A1 <% A](x: A1) = D(x.l :+ 'A')
implicit def bc[B1 <% B](x: B1) = C(x.l :+ 'B')
implicit def ce[C1 <% C](x: C1) = E(x.l :+ 'C')
implicit def ea[E1 <% E](x: E1) = A(x.l :+ 'E')

def pathFrom(end:D) = end

pathFrom(B(Nil))   // res0: D = D(List(B, C, E, A))
```