# Can Scala's implicits compose to convert higher-kinded types?

Tags: generics, scala, types, implicits

Let's say I have a type called LongArrayWritable, that is a boxed representation of an Array of Longs. I have implicit definitions that convert between these types:

```
implicit def boxLongArray(array: Array[Long]) : LongArrayWritable { /*elided*/}
implicit def unboxLongArray(array: LongArrayWritable) : Array[Long] { /*elided*/}
```

Now, I also have implicits that convert between java.lang.Iterable and scala.collection.List[X] in their generic form:

```
implicit def iterator2list[X](it : java.lang.Iterable[X]) : List[X] { /* elided */ }
implicit def list2iterator[X](list : List[X]) : java.lang.Iterable[X] { /* elided */ }
```

With these definitions, can the scala compiler infer an implicit conversion between java.lang.Iterable[LongArrayWritable] and List[Array[Long]] (the equivalent of `iterator2list(iterator).map(unboxLongArray(_))`), or is this beyond the capabilities of implicits, and therefore requires it's own (explicit?) implicit definition?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Just a stylistic comment; I tend to shy away from implicit conversions of this sort because I think that they hinder readability and obscure potentially costly operations. An example of what I believe is a preferable style can be found here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html (compare to JavaConversions in the same package)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what higher-kinded types have to do with this question; you're not abstracting over type constructors anywhere in this code.

Comment: Aah - both good points. I can appreciate how implicits can obscure the cost of a conversion operation - I had been attempting to remove all explicit casts from my code which may not have been a particularly good design decision. Regarding higher-kinded types, I think I may have muddled my terminology slightly here - I may well be confusing higher-kinded types with parameterised types. In fact, I'm not entirely clear on the distinction, but this is probably a seperate question entirely! :-)

Comment: In short, a higher-kinded type allows you to abstract over parameterized types. For example, `List[Int]` is a type; `List` is a type constructor of one argument; it is not a type itself. `List[Int]` is said to have kind `*`, while `List` has kind `* -> *` meaning that it requires another type to give a type. Now, imagine a trait `Foo[M[_]]` - here, you can parameterize Foo with any type constructor of one argument (kind `* -> *`), so for example you could create a `Foo[List]` or `Foo[Option]`, but not a `Foo[List[Int]]` since `List[Int]` has the wrong kind. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a post that covers this question: [How can I chain implicits in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala) . Essentially, you need to have a view bound for the conversion to `LongArrayWritable`. That means, the implicit `def` that converts to `LongArrayWritable` receives an implicit argument (called view bound) so that the argument to this `def` is not directly an `Array` but some type that can be converted to an `Array`:

```
object LongArrayWritable {
  implicit def fromArraySource[A <% Array[Long]](a: A): LongArrayWritable = apply(a)
}
case class LongArrayWritable(a: Array[Long])

def test(a: LongArrayWritable): Unit = println("OK")
```

now this works for Arrays:

```
test(Array( 1L, 2L, 3L))
```

however, since `Array` is not an `Iterable` and there are no default conversions from `Iterable` to `Array` in scope, you need to add one:

```
implicit def iterable2Array[A: ClassManifest](i: Iterable[A]): Array[A] = i.toArray
```

then it works:

```
test(List(1L, 2L, 3L))
```

the view bound `A <% Array[Long]` is a shortcut for an implicit argument of type `A => Array[Long]`, so you could have also written

```
implicit def fromArraySource[A](a: A)(implicit view: A => Array[Long]) ...
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the delay in replying. That's all very clear now!