# Question about views in Scala

Tags: scala, view, implicit-conversion

I saw examples, where a conversion function `T => S` is passed as an implicit parameter. Scala [calls](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/130) this function `view` and even provides special syntax sugar -- `view bound` -- for that case .

However we already have implicit conversions ! Can I replace these `views` (i.e. conversion functions passed as implicit parameters) with implicit conversions ? ? What I can do with `views` what I can't with implicit conversions ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My understanding of your question is, what would be the advantage of

```
case class Num(i: Int)
implicit def intToNum(i: Int) = Num(i)

def test[A <% Num](a: A): Int = a.i
test(33)
```

over

```
def test2(a: Num): Int = a.i
test2(33)
```

Yes? Well the meaning of view is exactly that: the type T can be viewed as another type S. Your method or function might want to deal with T in the first place. An example is Ordered:

```
def sort[A <% Ordered[A]](x: A, y: A): (A, A) = if (x < y) (x, y) else (y, x)

sort(1, 2)     // --> (1,2)
sort("B", "A") // --> (A,B)
```

Two more use cases for view bounds:

- you may want to convert from T to S only under certain circumstances, e.g. lazily
  (this is in a way the same situation as above: you basically want to work with T)
- you may want to chain implicit conversions. See this post: [How can I chain implicits in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala)

Answer (score 3):

What you call implicit conversions is nothing more than a view in global scope.

View bounds are necessary in when using type parameters, as it is a sign that an implicit conversion is necessary. For example:

```
def max[T](a: T, b: T): T = if (a < b) b else a
```

Because there's no constrains whatsoever on `T`, the compiler doesn't know that a `<` method will be available. Let's see the compiler let you go ahead with that, then consider these two calls:

```
max(1, 2)
max(true, false)
```

There's nothing in the signature `max[T](a: T, b: T): T` that tells the compiler it should not allow the second call, but should allow the first. This is where view bounds come in:

```
def max[T <% Ordered[T]](a: T, b: T): T = if (a < b) b else a
```

That not only tells the compiler where the `<` method comes from, but also tells the compiler that `max(true, false)` is not valid.