# Can Scala apply multiple implicit conversions in one expression?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I chain implicits in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala)

**Can Scala apply multiple implicit conversions in one expression?**

Consider this simple example:

```
  case class Wrapper(s: String)

  case class WrapperWrapper(w: Wrapper)

  implicit def string2Wrapper(s: String) = Wrapper(s)

  implicit def wrapper2WrapperWrapper(w: Wrapper) = WrapperWrapper(w)

  // implicit conversation -->  w = string2Wrapper("w")
  val w: Wrapper = "w"

  // implicit conversation -->  ww = wrapper2WrapperWrapper(w)
  val ww: WrapperWrapper = w

  // does NOT compile!
  // ideally --> sad = wrapper2WrapperWrapper(string2Wrapper("ww"))
  val sad: WrapperWrapper = "ww"
```

**Is there any way to get the "double" conversion in the last line to work?**

I can help things along by defining another implicit like:

```
implicit def string2WrapperWrapper(s:String) = wrapper2WrapperWrapper(s)
```

but it seems like that shouldn't be necessary...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't have a concise reference to hand (the answer is scattered through 6.26 and chapter 7 of [The Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)), but the answer is **no**.

This is due to practicality - double implicit conversions would square the number of possible conversions available, greatly increasing the chance of collisions and making it harder to work out exactly what would happen with a given conversion.

It's not ideal that you have to declare the `String` to `WrapperWrapper` conversion yourself; but given how rarely you need to do this in practice, compared to the potential confusion of double implicits, I do consider it the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 5):

You can coerce the sequence of conversions fairly concisely:

```
scala>   val sad: WrapperWrapper = ("ww": Wrapper)           
sad: WrapperWrapper = WrapperWrapper(Wrapper(ww))
```

As explained by @Andrzej Doyle, two conversions at a time magnifies the risk of accidental conversions happening and so it is dissallowed.