# Scala with implicit class coupled with implicit conversions

Tags: scala, parsing, playframework-2.0, implicit

a try to add non-backtracking ~> and <~ to my parser based on RegexParsers.

[RegexParsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers) implement `implicit def literal(s: String): Parser[String]` witch transphorm implicitly a String to a Parser[String]

now i add :

```
`object implicits{

       implicit class helper[T](parser  : Parser[T])  { 
           def ~>! [U](q: => Parser[U]): Parser[U] = parser ~! q ^^ {case a ~ b => b} named ("~>!") 
           def <~! [U](q: => Parser[U]): Parser[T] = parser ~! q ^^ {case a ~ b => a} named ("<~!") 
       }  
}
```

Witch is my implicit class.

But i seen a strange thing

```
def groupe : Parser[Group] =  "group(" ~>! identifier <~!  ")"
```

identifier is a Parser

Here i got an error when the string is pass in class parameter  `"group(" ~>! identifier` because the implicit is not made and the compiler look for ~>! inside String.

but when it's passed in the method parameter `identifier <~!  ")"` the String->Parser[String] implicit work.

Is it a Scala bug or i just miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a bug. The problem is that to resolve `~>!` on `String` the compiler would have to chain two implicit conversions: from `String` to `Parser` and from `Parser` to `helper`, which isn't allowed. So you need to add a direct conversion from `String` to `helper`:

```
implicit def stringToHelper(s: String): helper[String] = new helper(literal(s))
```

and also from `Regex` to `helper` if necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks, and for the method parameter it's just one conversion.
Why it's not allowed ? I feel that like a frustration. Add direct conversion work in this case but in the case where we don't know how many conversion there is it's will become a true problem.

Thank for your answer znd sorry for my english

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala

Comment: Because if it was allowed 1) the compiler would take more times searching for implicits before stopping search and saying the method is really not available (and the build times are bad enough already); 2) you would often get ambiguous implicits more often.