# Scala implicit search depth

Tags: scala, implicit

A simple example:

```
class A
class B
class C

object testobject {
  val a = new A
  implicit def b(a:A):B = new B
  implicit def c(b:B) = new C
  val b:B = a
  val c:C = a 
}
```

The last line doesn't compile. We have A=>B and B=>C implicit conversions defined but that doesn't infer A=>C.

It would be really nice to be able to have layers of implicit conversions work.

My particular problem. too long to post fully is actually from a web framework. I want to do something like:

```
A => Secure[A] => Format[A]
```

with the following

```
implicit def secure[A](a:A):Secure[A] = ???
implicit def format[A](sec:Secure[A]):Format[A] = ???
```

So I want to handle security and formatting through implicit magic, and only secured outputs can be formatted.

Has anybody found any tricks to make this, or something like this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered quite well here:

[How can I chain implicits in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala)

In short Scala does not chain implicit conversions, it only looks for direct conversion A => B. However, using additional implicit parameters the desired effect can be achieved.