# What is the functionality of the <% operator?

Tags: scala

Recently, I looked at the example of [implicit chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala), `implicit def foo[C3 <% C](c: C)`. I think I am confused about the difference between <% and (implicit c : C).

If I write implicit def bToC[C3 <: C](c: C)(implicit c3 : C3), it gives a compilation error, but why is that, implicit def should be in the scope?

**Edit:**

Can someone explain why

`implicit def aToB[A1 : A](a: A1)(implicit ev: Int => A1): B = new B(a.n, a.n)`

and

`implicit def aToB[A1 <: A](a: A1)(implicit ev: Int => A1): B = new B(a.n, a.n)`

are not working ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It is called "view bound" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds

Answer (score 1):

`[C3 <% C]` means `implicit ev: C3 => C`. In other word, an implicit function that converts `C3` to `C`. So all `C3` objects in the scope can be `C` objects.

```
def intPlus1[A <% Int](a: A) = a + 1
// def intPlus1[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => Int) = a + 1

implicit def string2int(s: String) = s.toInt // String => Int

intPlus1("100")
intPlus1("100")(string2int)
// the result bark bark
```

Note that `A <% A` for any `A`, because an implicit function `A => A` is `Predef`'ed, thus `B <% A` if `B <: A` too, as @rightfold mentions in the comment. :)

Comment: Note that this includes subtyping relationships, so α <: β → α <% β.

Comment: but why implicit def aToB[A1 : A](a: A1)(implicit ev: Int => A1): B = new B(a.n, a.n) and implicit def aToB[A1 <: A](a: A1)(implicit ev: Int => A1): B = new B(a.n, a.n) are not working ?

Comment: @Cloudtech There's no way I can answer to the question while the definition of `A`, `A1` and `B` is not provided :P