# How can I chain generic implicits in Scala?

Tags: scala, slick, implicit-conversion, slick-3.0, implicits

There is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala) that discusses chaining of implicits but I think it doesn't cover my case because I have generic implicits. Sample project that demonstrates the issue is located [here](https://github.com/cppexpert/slick-columns-test). To reproduce [these](https://github.com/cppexpert/slick-columns-test/blob/master/src/main/scala/co/greenhouse/rabbit/server/db/PostgresTables.scala#L74-L75) two lines should be commented out.

So I have number of implicits vals for concrete types such as

```
implicit val ObjectIdColumnType: ColumnType[ObjectId] = MappedColumnType.base[ObjectId, Array[Byte]](
      { obj => obj.toByteArray }, { arr => new ObjectId(arr) }
    )
```

I'd like all of them automagically produce `GetResult[T]` implicit vals. Thus I wrote following function

```
implicit def getResultForTypedTypes[T](implicit bct: ColumnType[T]): GetResult[T] =
  GetResult[T](r => bct.getValue(r.rs, r.currentPos))
```

and I expect that function with prototype such as

```
def << [T](implicit f: GetResult[T]): T = f(this)
```

would be able to pick up `GetResult[ObjectId]`

Sadly I get error

```
Error:(78, 20) could not find implicit value for parameter f: slick.jdbc.GetResult[org.bson.types.ObjectId]
      val id = r.<<[ObjectId]
                   ^
```

I enabled log-implicits and found that seemingly unrelated implicit gets in a way

```
Information:(78, 20) getResultForTypedTypes is not a valid implicit value for slick.jdbc.GetResult[org.bson.types.ObjectId] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value strListTypeMapper in object MyAPI of type => co.greenhouse.rabbit.server.db.MyPostgresDriver.DriverJdbcType[List[String]]
 and value ObjectIdColumnType in object MyAPI of type => co.greenhouse.rabbit.server.db.MyPostgresDriver.BaseColumnType[org.bson.types.ObjectId]
 match expected type co.greenhouse.rabbit.server.db.MyPostgresDriver.api.BaseColumnType[T]
      val id = r.<<[ObjectId]
                   ^
```

How can I find the issue in this spaghetti of implicits ?

Comment: From what I can see `DriverJdbcType` is in some strange convoluted way a subtype of `BaseColumnType`. That still doesn't explain the `List[String]` though...