# Parameterized method with Ordering?

Tags: scala, variance, type-parameter

Now I am confused. I am quite new on Scala, having worked with it for a few weeks, I think I am getting familiar with it, but I am stuck on the apparently trivial following case.

I cannot find the Scala equivalent to this Java declaration :

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> myMethod(List<T> values) {
  // ...
  final List<T> sorted = new ArrayList<T>(values);
  Collections.sort(sorted);
  // ...
}
```

I thought the following would do :

```
def myMethod[A >: Ordering[A]](values: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = {
  // ...
  val sorted = values.sorted
  //
}
```

However, I get the following errors:

> error: illegal cyclic reference involving type A
>
> error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[A]
> starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering

Where am I wrong?

Comment: it should be A **<:** Ordering[A],  A is a subtype of (i.e. extends) Ordering[A]. That way it should compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be a context bound, as shown below.

```
scala> def myMethod[A : Ordering](values: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = values.sorted
myMethod: [A](values: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$1: Ordering[A])Seq[A]
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, `Ordering` is akin to `Comparator`, not `Comparable`. The Scala equivalent to `Comparable` is `Ordered`. Next, `extends` equivalent is `<:`, not `>:`. The latter is equivalent to `super` -- `T super COmparable<T>`, which is not what you want. So, with both these fixes in, your code should look like this:

```
def myMethod[A <: Ordered[A]](values: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = {
  // ...
  val sorted = values.sorted
  //
}
```

However, this won't work for `Seq[Int]`, for instance, since `Int` does not extend `Ordered` -- just like Java's `int` does not extend `Comparable` (or anything else, since it is not a class).

Scala has a work-around for that -- an implicit conversion from certain classes to an `Ordered` class. To use that, however, you need to use a [view bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/context-and-view-bounds-again), which would make the code look like this:

```
def myMethod[A <% Ordered[A]](values: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = {
  // ...
  val sorted = values.sorted
  //
}
```

See `<%` instead of `<:`? That's the view bound.

Now, the current preference in Scala circles is to use context bounds instead of view bounds, as they are more flexible. That would mean using `Ordering`, in the manner described by the other answers.