# Sort unbound Comparable in Scala

Tags: scala, comparable

I am somewhat familiar with sorting in Scala using `Ordering`'s, however I would like to sort some objects which are defined in Java. They are `Comparable` (not `Comparable[T]`) and `final`:

```
final class Term implements Comparable { ... }
```

(this is actually Lucene's Term class, and no I can't change the version of Lucene).

I first hoped there was an implicit somewhere:

```
terms.sorted //fail - no implicit ordering
```

So maybe I could make it ordered?

```
class OrderedTerm extends Term with Ordering[Term] //fail - class is final
```

After this I thought I'd resort to the nastiness of using `java.util.Collections.sort`:

```
Collections.sort(terms) // error: inferred type arguments [org.apache.lucene.index.Term] do not conform to method sort's type parameter bounds [T <: java.lang.Comparable[_ >: T]]
```

So it seems even this doesn't work as Scala is strict with it's type parameters. At this point I can see two ways to go: reimplement another explicit ordering (bad) or write the sort in Java (not quite as bad).

Is there some way to do this cleanly in Scala? I assume that this situation may be common using legacy Java objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Ordering` (as opposed to `Ordered`) is separate from the compared type. It is equivalent to java `Comparator`, not `Comparable`. So you simply define you ordering on Terms as a singleton, there is no problem with inheriting `Term`.

```
implicit object TermOrdering extends Ordering[Term] {
  def compare(t1: Term, t2: Term: Term): Int = ....
}
```

Better mark it implicit because it will be convenient to have it in implicit scope. Then you just have to ensure that `TermOdering` is imported when you call some operation that needs it.

P.S. You should read this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds/4467012#4467012) by Daniel Sobral.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right that I screwed up the OrderedTerm definition - I meant `Ordered` not `Ordering`.

I was avoiding your solution because I thought that I'd have to reimplement the actual ordering method, but I don't:

    implicit object TermOrdering extends Ordering[Term] {
        def compare(t1: Term, t2: Term): Int = t1.compareTo(t2)
    }