# Scala manifest and instances

Tags: scala

I'm using Jerkson, and I need to check if a given class can be serialized. The java version just needs a class, but jerkson does this:

```
 def canSerialize[A](implicit mf: Manifest[A]) = mapper.canSerialize(mf.erasure)
```

Given that I have an instance, how can I call this? I pretty much tried

```
canSerialize[ClassManifest.fromClass(foo)]
```

But its not working. I wonder why the guys at jerkson could not make it simpler by just making this: canSerialize(Class[_]) ...

Any ideas on how can I invoke this?

Edit:

I fixed this by using:

```
canSerilialize(Manifest.classType(foo.getClass))
```

Comment: Adding more context: If I try to use the canSerialize(ClassManifest.fromClass(foo)) I get the following:


type mismatch;  found   : scala.reflect.ClassManifest[?0] where type ?0 <: com.acme.domain.Foo  required: Manifest[?]

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
canSerialize[Foo]
```

Compiler can automatically generate manifest for you (if it has enough type information in context)

Since Scala 2.8.0 `canSerialize` can be written via *context bound*. See [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467012/721668)

Comment: Problem is that I don't know the type in advance. I tried ClassManifest.fromClass(foo.getClass) but its not working. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the class in advance, you can always pass the manifest as a parameter, i.e. this should work: `canSerialize( Manifest.classType( foo.getClass ) )`.

Comment: This is actually what I tried on the question and it does not work.