# What does the <% operator mean in Scala generics?

Tags: scala, generics, specs2

In specs2 there is a method called Around, [documented here](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Around) that has the following example:

```
object http extends Around {
  def around[T <% Result](t: =>T) = openHttpSession("test") {
    t  // execute t inside a http session
  }
}
```

The source for this code can be found [here](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/1.11/src/main/scala/org/specs2/specification/Around.scala).

I'm curious what the <% operator means in this context?

**EDIT:** here is a solid answer on this subject, [What are Scala context and view bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds)

Comment: Google is painful to use to search for symbols, but PDF viewers are pretty good: take a look at the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (or "SLS"). The term for this type restriction is "View Bounds".

Comment: I had to use this symbol-specific search engine to find it: http://symbolhound.com/

Answer (score 5):

This is a view bound. It means, that the type `T` must be convertible to the type `Result`. For more information about type bounds I recommend you http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~brecht/courses/702/Possible-Readings/scala/ProgrammingInScala.pdf, starting at page 61.