# view bounds are deprecated; use an implicit parameter instead

Tags: scala, implicit, deprecation-warning, scala-2.13

I recently upgraded to Scala 2.13, and now am being warned about a deprecation. My function looks like so:

```scala
implicit def convertGeneralResult[A <% ToResponseMarshallable, B <% ToResponseMarshallable](r: Either[A, B]) =
  r.fold[ToResponseMarshallable](identity, identity)
```

The deprecation warning reads (I actually have two of them, one for each type parameter A/B):

> view bounds are deprecated; use an implicit parameter instead.
> example: instead of `def f[A <% Int](a: A)` use `def f[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A => Int)`

I'm not entirely sure how to apply the suggested fix in my case though.

Comment: Note that **implicit conversions** _(which is what **view bounds** are)_ are considered a bad practice, it would be good to try to redactor that code to do not depend on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many depths into this question, but I'll give only some references in case you want to deep dive into it, and how to fix it as well.

Already in 2013, in Scala 2.11 you can find a bug in Scala called [deprecation warning for view bounds under -Xfuture](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7629). At the time [this was implemented](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2909), but in case you didn't use the `-Xfuture` option in [SCALA COMPILER OPTIONS](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html) you weren't aware of that.

In 2018 [Deprecate view bounds without -Xfuture](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10719) was opened, which [was merged into Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6500) as you noticed.

As another reference, there is a similar question [Scala 2.13.0 deprecates <%, but how do I get rid of this in a class definition](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/scala-2-13-0-deprecates-but-how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-in-a-class-definition/4679).

Now to your issue. All you need to do is remove the `<%` usage, and replace those with implicits:

```
implicit def convertGeneralResult[A, B](r: Either[A, B])(implicit aToMarshallable: A => ToResponseMarshallable, bToMarshallable: B => ToResponseMarshallable) =
  r.fold[ToResponseMarshallable](identity, identity)
```

Comment: Oh I see! I was confused in that I thought I had to actually *explicitly* invoke the implicit parameter within my function to convert the parameters to fold. But I don’t have to, it’s enough to to simply declare the implicits, which implies there must exist an implicit that takes the types from A/B to `ResponseMarshallable[A/B]`. Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4465948/2359227) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11516961/2359227) post for more information. Basically it means that `A`/`B` can convert to `ToResponseMarshallable`.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. `ToResponseMarsallable` as you said (and without the type parameter) :)