# Meaning of additional colon in Scala class parametrization

Tags: scala, generics, types

What does `[A : Manifest : WireFormat]` mean in the following code?  It's from `com.nicta.scoobi.TextInput` (available on github). It doesn't seem to be any of the usual type bounds.

```
  def fromDelimitedTextFile[A : Manifest : WireFormat]
      (path: String, sep: String = "\t")
      (extractFn: PartialFunction[List[String], A])
    : DList[A] = {

    val lines = fromTextFile(path)
    lines.flatMap { line =>
      val fields = line.split(sep).toList
      if (extractFn.isDefinedAt(fields)) List(extractFn(fields)) else Nil
    }
  }
```

Where can I find more information about this topic?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is called a context bound. They are syntactic sugar for an implicit parameter list:

```
def meth[A : ContextBound1 : ContextBoundN](a: A)

// ==>

def meth[A](a: A)(implicit evidence: ContextBound1[A], ContextBoundN[A])
```

If there are multiple context bounds from 1 to N, they are all translated into the same parameter list. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds) for a more detailed explanation about how they work and for what they are useful.

To find such symbols it is useful to read the [StackOverflow Scala Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info).