# Generic function with implicit argument

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to generalize one of the functions I use for returning Json from a Play action.

I currently do it like this:

```
def JsendOkObj(obj: JsValue) = Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "success", "data" -> obj))
```

and call it:

```
JsendOkObj(Json.toJson(myObj))
```

I'd like to do something more like:

```
def JsendOkObj[A](obj: A) = Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "success", "data" -> Json.toJson(obj)))
```

and then call it like:

```
JsendOkObj(myObj)
```

where `Json.toJson` is [defined](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.1-RC2/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json%24) as:

```
def toJson[A](implicit arg0: Writes[A]): Enumeratee[A, JsValue]
```

The error I get compiling this is that I need to define a Writes for type `A`. Which is not possible here since I don't know which type `A` will actually end up being:

> No Json deserializer found for type A. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can ensure that an implicit `Writes[A]` will be in scope when you call `toJSon` by adding an implicit parameter list to your own method, like this:

```
def JsendOkObj[A](obj: A)(implicit w: Writes[A]) =
  Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "success", "data" -> Json.toJson(obj)))
```

Which is equivalent to passing the type class instance explicitly to `toJson`:

```
def JsendOkObj[A](obj: A)(implicit w: Writes[A]) =
  Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "success", "data" -> Json.toJson(obj)(w)))
```

Note that you could also use [a context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467012/334519) here:

```
def JsendOkObj[A: Writes](obj: A) =
  Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "success", "data" -> Json.toJson(obj)))
```

This is just syntactic sugar for my first version above.