# Scala - TreeSet of tuples

Tags: scala, comparable, treeset

I am trying to instantiate a TreeSet in scala, passing a specific comparator on tuples like this:

```
  var heads: java.util.TreeSet[(T, Int)] = new java.util.TreeSet[(T, Int)](new Comparator[(T,Int)] {
    def compare(o1: (T, Int), o2: (T, Int)): Int = Ordering[(T, Int)].compare(o1, o2)
  })
```

However, an implicit ordering on T cannot be found. Should I specify that T <: Comparable[T] in the type hierarchy or is there a simple wayto achieve tuple comparison?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `: Ordering` ([context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467012/406435)) to the definition of `T`.

For method:

```
def method[T: Ordering] = {
  var heads: ...
}
```

For class:

```
class MyClss[T: Ordering] {
  var heads: ...
}
```

There is implicit object `Ordering[T]` for each subtype of `Comparable`. But also there are such objects for many other types. For instance for `TupleN`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing tuples, you also need to specify which element to use for comparisons, e.g. if you want to order by the first element of type `T`:

```
object Main extends App {
  import java.util.Comparator
  def heads[T: Ordering] = new java.util.TreeSet[(T, Int)](new Comparator[(T,Int)] {
    def compare(o1: (T, Int), o2: (T, Int)): Int = Ordering.by[(T, Int), T](_._1).compare(o1, o2)
  })
  val test = heads[String]
  test.add(("Foo", 42))
  test.add(("Foo", 42))
  test.add(("Bar", 17))
  println(test)
}
```

This will output `[(Bar,17), (Foo,42)]`.

Comment: Are there some particular reasons to use only 1 element for comparisons?

Comment: I wasn't aware that there are [predefined Orderings for Tuples](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering$), but there are, so `Ordering[(T, Int)].compare()` works as well, if you want to sort by _1, _2.