# Currying by second argument

Tags: scala

I need to implement quicksort with several ways to select pivot, so I've implemented a routine that takes a pivot chooser as a parameter. But definitions of concrete implementations contain lots of boilerplate, is there a more concise way to define them?

```
  private def qsort[a <% Ordered[a]](xs: Stream[a])(choosePivot:Stream[a] => a): Stream[a] = {
    if(xs.lengthCompare(1) <= 0) xs
    else {
      val pivot = choosePivot(xs)
      val l = xs.filter(_ < pivot)
      val r = xs.filter(_ > pivot)
      qsort(l)(choosePivot) ++ pivot#::qsort(r)(choosePivot)
    }
  }

  def qsortHead[a <% Ordered[a]](xs: Stream[a]) = qsort(xs)(ys => ys.head)

  def qsortLast[a <% Ordered[a]](xs: Stream[a]) = qsort(xs)(ys => ys.last)

  def qsortRandom[a <% Ordered[a]](xs: Stream[a]) = qsort(xs)(ys => ys(rng.nextInt(ys.length)))
```

In Haskell I could just write something like `qsortHead = qsort head` if the choose pivot function is the first parameter or `qsortHead xs = qsort xs (\ys -> head ys)` if it's the second. Is there something similar in Scala?

Comment: I guess  that `(ys => xs(rng.nextInt(xs.length)))` should read `(ys => ys(rng.nextInt(ys.length)))`

Comment: `qsortHead xs = qsort xs head`

Comment: @maasg yeah, that's some buggy code I've submitted, the qsort routine is also incorrect.

Comment: Multiple parameter lists are quite distinct from currying. You're talking about multiple parameters lists.

Comment: @RandallSchulz - I totally agree, and it really bugs me to see the two concepts mixed up. [Partially applied functions are not the same as curried functions!](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Currying&oldid=574918105#Contrast_with_partial_function_application) Unfortunately, the Scala community seems to enjoy conflating "multiple parameter lists" and "curried."  [Even Odersky's book seems to mix the two together](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/glossary.html#g575993339), or at least blur the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

For the lambda expressions making use of the passed parameter, the underscore syntax is your friend: `_.head`

```
qsort(xs)(_.head)
```

`_.head` will be translated to the full expression `x => x.head`

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that [`Ordered`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordered) has been mostly phased out of the Scala standard library in favor of the more general [`Ordering`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering). Unless you have a good reason for using the former that I don't know about, the latter is probably a better choice.

It might not be much better, but if you use `Ordering` at least you can get rid of the ugly `<%` operators. I'd also recommend using the same lambda shorthand that @maasg suggested (note that you can't use it for the more complex Random lambda though):

```
def qsortHead[A: Ordering](xs: Stream[A]) = qsort(xs)(_.head)
def qsortLast[A: Ordering](xs: Stream[A]) = qsort(xs)(_.last)
def qsortRandom[A: Ordering](xs: Stream[A]) = qsort(xs)(ys => ys(rng.nextInt(ys.length)))
```

You can look at this question if you want more info on the difference between the view-bound `Ordered` and context-bound `Ordering`: [*What are Scala context and view bounds?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds)

Due to the way that Scala handles generic types and does type inference, you're going to be stuck with a bunch of boilerplate pretty much no matter what. The above is probably about as succinct as you're going to be able to get.