# Scala Implicit parameter bound

Tags: scala, implicit, type-parameter

I'm struggling with the following problem which throws an error at compile-time " error: value dir is not a member of type parameter A". But it is!

```
trait Logger { def dir: String }

trait LoggerFile[A <: Logger] {
  def extractor: String => Option[A]
}

def getHistory[A: LoggerFile](): String = {
  implicitly[LoggerFile[A]].extractor("abc") match {
    case Some(a) => a.dir
    case None => ""
  }
}
```

I was able to overcome the problem by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds):

```
def getHistory[A <: Logger]()(implicit env: LoggerFile[A]): String = {
```

But I would have preferred the system to work before the transformation, i.e. with the syntactic sugar.
Is there a way to specify multiple type constraints on A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put all the constraints together.

After changing the type signature to

```
def getHistory[ A <: Logger : LoggerFile ](): String
```

your example compiles just fine.

Comment: Great. I tried the other way round : LoggerFile <: Logger but it did not work.