# how to write parametric-typed function where the parameter class declares some method(s) in scala?

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I deal with Scala problem which I can't properly name, so maybe there is already answer somewhere here (please be patient).

Assuming this code:

```
class A {def foo() = 5}
class B {def foo() = 6}
def fooer[T](x:T) = x.foo()
```

I get error:

```
<console>:7: error: value foo is not a member of type parameter T
    def fooer[T](x:T) = x.foo
```

This perfectly makes sense as compiler can't possibly know what type `T` will be passed. So finally the question - how can I implement typed function so it accepts only types with `foo` method declared?

Please note that I don't seek `enum` alternitives (see [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Either.html)) as I don't know how many classes are there (external library). Also the classes have no common predecessor class or trait and they can't be modified.

Is this even possible? C++ language support this behavior using templates. I prefer solution which doesn't use reflection API.

Thanks :)

I tried some more definitions of `fooer` such as

```
def fooer[T <: {def foo(): Integer}](x:T) = x.foo()
fooer[A](new A)
<console>:10: error: type arguments [A] do not conform to method fooer's type parameter bounds [T <: AnyRef{def foo(): Integer}]
          fooer[A](new A)
               ^
```

but with no success

Comment: Lee's answer matches the question nicely.  Though I recommend you also look up ad-hoc polymorphism http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `A.foo` returns an `Int` not an `Integer`. If you change your method to:

```
def fooer[T <: {def foo(): Int}](x:T) = x.foo()
```

then it will work.

Comment: You could also simplify to `def fooer(x: { def foo(): Int }) = x.foo()`

Comment: This does use reflection under the hood.  But without C++ style templates and all the code generation that entails, there's no way to avoid it.