# What does ":" means in method type in scala?

Tags: scala, generics

Here is the method signature example:

```
someMethod [A <: BaseType : SecondType : ClassTag]

trait BaseType {}

trait SecondType[A] {}
```

ClassTag is scala.reflect.ClassTag

What does ":" means?

Does BaseType influence to SecondType or/and ClassTag parametrization?

For me when I see `[A <: BaseType]` I understand that I should call `someMethod` with type parameter that implements/extends trait `BaseType`, but what other parameters are used for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are Scala context and view bounds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds)

Comment: There are only examples like `(A:a, B,b)`, not likle `(A:a:b:c)`.

Comment: Why are there questions about "what are all the uses of underscore" but not "what are all the uses of colon?"  or "dot?" or "dollar?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's probably obvious to someone, but:

```
scala> trait X[A] ; trait Y[A]

scala> def f[A : X : Y] = 42
```

yields

```
    def f[A](implicit evidence$1: X[A], evidence$2: Y[A]) = 42
```

under `-Xprint:parser`. So it wants both X[A] and Y[A].

Comment: I suggest somethink like that, but not sure. Thanks a lot.