# Scala Ordering[T] and Serializable

Tags: scala

Given a case class like this:

```
case class KVPair[
    K <: Ordering[K] with Serializable, 
    VV <: Serializable
](key: K, value: VV)
```

How would I go about constructing a `KVPair` with `Longs`, something like this:

```
def createKVPair(): KVPair[Long, Long] = {
    KVPair(1L, 1L)
}
```

The compiler keeps complaining with:

> Long does not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds.

Comment: I assume this is because `Long` is not an `Ordering`. Have you tried `K <% Comparable`?

Comment: I believe B. Kemmer is right. Long is per definition Ordering, and Ordering inherits from Serializable. It is beyond me why this won't work.

Comment: That is true. So Long does not extend Ordering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things going on here.  First of all `Long` does not extend `Ordering[Long]`.  [The page you linked from the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.math.Ordering$$Long$) in the comments is the documentation of an implicit object called `Long` in the `scala.math.Ordering` package.

However, that object is very relevant here.  Since that object is in implicit scope, you can use a *context bound* to ensure that there is an instance of `Ordered[Long]` is available, which will allow code to order your `Longs`.

```
case class Key[K : Ordering](key: K)
```

This will allow you to do `Key(1L)`.

Your other problem is that `Long` is also not `Serializable`, so the second generic parameter is also problematic.  `Long` is implicitly viewable as a `java.io.Serializable`, which might be of interest to you here.  You can use a *view bound* to ensure that `K` and `V` have this constraint:

```
type JS = java.io.Serializable
case class KVPair[K <% JS : Ordering, V <% JS](key: K, value: V)
```

The context-bound and view-bound syntax make this equivalent to:

```
 case class KVPair[K, V](key: K, value: V)(
    implicit kev1: Ordering[K], 
             kev2: K => JS, 
             vev1: V => JS
 )
```

You can read more about context bounds and view bounds on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds).

Answer (score 2):

`scala.Long` is not an `Ordering`. The type bound `K <: Ordering[K]` means `K` should must be bounded by the `Ordering` type. And `scala.Long` most certainly does not extend the type class `Ordering`. There exists an instance of an `Ordering[Long]`, but `scala.Long` does not extend it.

What you want is evidence of an `Ordering[K]`, ie., a *context bound*. Something like this:

```
case class KVPair[K : Ordering , VV](key: K, value: VV)

def createKVPair(): KVPair[Long, Long] = {
    KVPair(1L, 1L)
}
```

The above case class is syntactic sugar for:

```
case class KVPair[K, VV](key: K, value: VV)(implicit ev: Ordering[K])
```

You may have noticed that I've also removed the `Serializable` bound. This is because `Long` is not `Serializable`, so it cannot possibly work with that constraint.

```
scala> implicitly[Long <:< Serializable]
<console>:26: error: Cannot prove that Long <:< Serializable.
              implicitly[Long <:< Serializable]
```