# Operators on parametrized type in Scala

Tags: scala

Given a higher order function that takes a function of type (A,A) => Boolean as a parameter:

```
 def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered :  (A,A) => Boolean) : Boolean =
 {
   def doSorted(i: Int) : Boolean = 
     if (i >= as.length-1) true
     else if (ordered(as(i), as(i+1))) false
     else doSorted(i+1)

  doSorted(0)
 }
 val lst1 = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I can declare a function with known parameter types and pass it in:

```
 def gtr(a : Int, b : Int) : Boolean = {
   a > b
 }

isSorted(lst1,gtr) /* works :-) */
```

I'd like to do one of the following. None of which seem to work for me:

1. Use a function with parametrised types:

   ```
    def gtr[T](a : T, b : T) : Boolean = {
         a > b    /* gives value > is not a member of type parameter T */
    }
   ```

   Is this possible in Scala. Do I have to tell the compiler that T is
   inherited from an object that has a >  operator?
2. Use an anonymous function:

   ```
   isSorted(lst1, ((x,y) => x > y)) /* gives missing parameter type */
   ```
3. Use Scala underscore magic to pass the > operator

   ```
   isSorted(lst1, _>_) /* gives missing parameter type */
   ```

None of these three options work for me and I'm struggling to work out why. Can anyone tell me which of the above approaches are valid in Scala and what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your type parameter `A` has no restrictions on it, which means you can pass any type. But that can't be, because not every type has a `>` method, like you say. There is also no generic type that other types with `>` inherit from, either. The only option left is type classes, for which we have the [Ordering](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering) type class. You will need to require that an `Ordering[A]` exists (implicitly) in the signature of your method.

I'll do it for the `greater` method, with one caveat. We will need to curry the parameters of `isSorted`.

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A])(ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
    def doSorted(i: Int) : Boolean = 
        if (i >= as.length - 1) true
        else if (ordered(as(i), as(i + 1))) false
        else doSorted(i + 1)

    doSorted(0)
}
```

Now we define `greater` to implicitly find an `Ordering[A]`. Once we have one, we can use its `gt` method to make the actual comparison.

```
def greater[A: Ordering](a: A, b: A): Boolean = implicitly[Ordering[A]].gt(a, b)
```

This is the same as:

```
def greater[A](a: A, b: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): Boolean = ord.gt(a, b)
```

Usage:

```
scala> isSorted(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))(greater _)
res88: Boolean = true

scala> isSorted(Array(1, 4, 3, 4))(greater _)
res89: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right. You need to specify, that T can be compared.
One approach is to use view bounds:

```
    def gtr[T <% Ordered[T]](a : T, b : T) : Boolean = {
      a > b  
 }
```

`[T <% Ordered[T]]` can be read as "**`T`** may be *viewed* as an **`Ordered[T]`**" (extended or implicitly converted). 
This approach is now deprecated https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629), so you may use implicit evidence to convert `T` to `Ordered[T]`

```
def gtr[T](a : T, b : T)(implicit toOrdered: T => Ordered[T]) : Boolean
```

A very nice post, which explains view bounds in more details: [What are Scala context and view bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds)

Regarding your 2nd and 3rd questions: in 2nd example, you need to infer the types for x and y to make code compile. 3rd - is just syntactic sugar for 2nd.
Both of them will compile.

```
isSorted(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6), ((x : Int,y: Int) => x > y))
isSorted(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6), ((_: Int) > (_: Int)))
```