# Meaning of <% in Scala and use in abstract class definition

Tags: scala, abstract-class, type-bounds

What is the meaning of <% in Scala?

The context I see it in is an abstract class declaration that I am trying to extend.  This is the important part of the class:

```
abstract class Index[Res <% Result[Res]]  {
    def results (term: String) : List[Res]  ...
```

This is the header of the Result trait:

```
trait Result[T] extends Any {
```

I was able to successfully create a class that extends Result.  For simplification here, I will use this header:

```
class Sample extends Result[Int] {
```

I want results in my class (extending Index) to return type List[Sample].  I tried a few different definitions, but I always get a similar error:

```
No implicit view available from [type] to Result[type]
```

where type is whatever type I used to extend Index, i.e. :

```
class SampleIndex extends Index[Sample]
```

I think my problem comes from my misunderstanding of the <% in the definition of the abstract class.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `<%` is a [*view bound*](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/130).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds

Answer (score 2):

It's a view bound. check more info [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/130)