# Tool for finding types satisfying a view bound in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I was reading [this](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/635e94f6b3d695663fb42ed13b458bed413afe63/core/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/vdom/Implicits.scala#L60) code:

```
  // Frag
  @inline implicit final def _react_fragReactNode[T <% ReactNode](v: T): Frag = new ReactNodeFrag(v)
```

and wanted to figure out what can be passed to `_react_fragReactNode`. I understand that `T` has to satisfy a [view bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds) but I do not want to go through all the implicits and inspect them all manually.

So I wonder if there is a way to figure out programmatically what `T`-s are allowed ? Is there a tool for that ?

For example IntelliJ supports finding all super and subtypes of a given type, I wonder if there is a similar tool that can find all the types which can be implicitly converted to a given type (in this case `ReactNode`)?