# What is TypeTag in Encoders.product?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, implicit

I use Spark 2.1.1.

I started off with the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val mySchema = StructType(
  StructField("id", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("code", StringType, false),
  StructField("value", DecimalType, false))
val myDS = Seq((1,"000010", 1.0), (2, "000020", 2.0)).as[mySchema]
```

Here I saw that mySchema was not a type and after looking at `Encoders.scala` I could see I needed to pass a subtype of Product here via

```
def product[T <: Product : TypeTag]: Encoder[T] = ExpressionEncoder()
```

So after seeing that the colon operator is just syntactical sugar for an implicit parameter from [What are Scala context and view bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds), I can see that there should be an implicit **TypeTag[T]** available but I don't understand though how **TypeTag[T]** is implicit from looking at `SQLImplicits.scala`.

```
   /**
   * @since 1.6.1
   * @deprecated use [[newSequenceEncoder]]
   */
  def newProductSeqEncoder[A <: Product : TypeTag]: Encoder[Seq[A]] = ExpressionEncoder()
```

Even though it's deprecated, when I look at

```
 /** @since 2.2.0 */
  implicit def newSequenceEncoder[T <: Seq[_] : TypeTag]: Encoder[T] = ExpressionEncoder()
```

I still wonder where is there a **TypeTag[T]** implicitly declared?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TypeTag` is a type class that will implicitly load an instance for any type you try to summon. This is independent from Spark or `SQLImplicits`, for example you can try this

```
def getMyTypeTag[T : TypeTag]: TypeTag[T] = implicitly[TypeTag[T]]
```

On the other hand a spark sql `Encoder` can be built by spark as soon as you import the implicits  defined in `SqlImplicits`, if you take a look to `LowPrioritySQLImplicits` you can see that you need the `TypeTag` to create the `Encoder` for `Product` (case classes), that's why you need to load the `TypeTag` in the implicit context

```
trait LowPrioritySQLImplicits {
  /** @since 1.6.0 */
  implicit def newProductEncoder[T <: Product : TypeTag]: Encoder[T] = Encoders.product[T]

}
```

The TypeTag can be summoned only if the code from where you are trying to summon the Encoder is not generic or the TypeTag is already in the context. For Example

```
def loadEncoder(): Encoder[MyType] ={
    import spark.implicits._
    Encoder[MyType] // The type is here so it will work
}
```

on the other hand

```
loadEncoder[MyType]
def loadEncoder[T](): Encoder[T] ={
    import spark.implicits._
    Encoder[T] // The type info is not here so it wont work
}
```

and

```
loadEncoder[MyType]
def loadEncoder[T: TypeTag](): Encoder[T] ={
    import spark.implicits._
    Encoder[T] // The type info is not here but the TypeTag is so it will work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I thought it was a Spark thing, but there is an import statement at the top of the page

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
```

When I look at the API page http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.TypeTags  I can see it's being handled here.