# How to pimp `String` as `Iterable[E]`

Tags: scala, scala-generics

I am working with Scala's `implicit class` mechanism and can't get `java.lang.String` recognized as `Iterable[A]`.

```
implicit class PStream[E](stream: Iterable[E]) {
    def splitOn(test: Iterable[E] => Boolean): Option[(Iterable[E], Iterable[E])] = {
        ???
    }
}
```

With just the above definition, IntelliJ and SBT state that ...

> Error:(31, 8) value splitOn is not a member of String
>   possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value splitOn'?
>                           .splitOn(s => Character.isWhitespace(s.head))

... when I try this ...

```
            line: String =>
                val Some((identifier: String, patternn: String)) =
                    line
                        // take the identifier
                        .splitOn(s => Character.isWhitespace(s.head))
```

Comment: That was a little bit unexpectedly quick accept. I've added a workaround proposal, just in case you are interested. The idea is to use implicit defs that require other implicit parameters that look more like typeclasses instead of implicit conversions. Those things tend to compose more nicely, and behave a bit more predictably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `Iterable[E]` is a Scala trait, and as such a relatively "recent" invention, whereas `java.lang.String` is a fundamental Java datatype that has been there since version 1.0. from 1995. Obviously, `java.lang.String` does not implement `Iterable[E]`.

Moreover, even if there is an implicit conversion from `String` to `Iterable[E]`, Scala will *never* attempt more than one implicit conversion on a single expression.

If you want to pimp `String`, you have to pass `String` as a single parameter to your implicit class. The compiler will refuse to build crazy towers of multiple implicit conversions, because it would make the compilation time inacceptable otherwise.

---

What you *could* try instead would be something like this:

```
implicit def toPStreamOps[X, E](x: X)(implicit iter: IsIterable[X, E])
: PStream[X, E] = ???
```

and then provide a separate

```
implicit object StringIsIterableChar 
extends IsIterable[String, Char] {
  def asIterable(s: String): Iterable[Char] = ???
}
```

This would give you pretty much the same functionality, but it would not require an uncontrolled explosion of implicit conversions.

Comment: "Scala will never attempt more than one implicit conversion on a single expression." is what I needed to hear.

Comment: @pal Note that it does not mean that you cannot [chain implicits (FAQ article)](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html).

Answer (score 0):

`String` (and also `Array[T]`) are inherited from Java and thus don't extend Scala's `Iterable`. In Scala though, there are implicit wrappers for `String` and `Array[T]` into objects that extend `IndexedSeq` and accordingly `Iterable`.

The original interface to request an implicit conversion of an argument was a [view bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds):

```
implicit class PStream[E, T <% Iterable[E]](stream: T) { 
  /* ... */
}
```

It is deprecated now, but you can just request the implicit conversion as an implicit argument:

```
implicit class PStream[E, T](stream: T)(implicit toIterable: T => Iterable[E]) { 
  /* ... */
}
```

This code will support normal `Iterable`s, and also `String`s and `Array`s.