# Scala - Method type parameters

Tags: scala, types, type-parameter, context-bound

I'm trying to understand some autogenerated code by the scala compiler but I don't know after what to search.

I have the following class:

```
trait Arrow1[F[_, _]]

abstract class Test {

  def f1[F[_, _] : Arrow1, A, B, C](fa: F[A,B], fb: F[A, C]): F[A, (B, C)]

  def f2[A: Seq, B](a: A): Boolean
}
```

After I decompiled the class file, the signature of the f1 and f2 methods look like:

```
public abstract class Test {
    public abstract <F, A, B, C> F f1(F var1, F var2, Arrow1<F> var3);

    public abstract <A, B> boolean f2(A var1, Seq<A> var2);
}
```

As you can see, the methods have an additional parameter. Where can I find some documentation about this method type parameter notation **F[_, _] : Arrow1** ?

Comment: Actually, it could be marked as duplicate: [What are Scala context and view bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds), but I decided to leave the quotes from the current spec instead of redirecting to an answer from 2010 (it's not like much has changed w.r.t. context bounds, but still...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for **"context bounds"**.

When you look up ["Type parameters"](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#type-parameters) in the Spec, you encounter `A: B` in the first paragraph, and you also get the link to [Context Bounds and View Bounds](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/07-implicits.html#context-bounds-and-view-bounds), where it says
*(Quote slightly changed, simplified to case with single context bound)*:

> A type parameter `A` of a method or non-trait class may also have one or
>   more context bounds `A : T`. In this case the type parameter may be
>   instantiated to any type `S` for which evidence exists at the
>   instantiation point that `S` satisfies the bound `T`. Such evidence
>   consists of an implicit value with type `T[S]`.
>
> A method or class containing type parameters with view or context
>   bounds is treated as being equivalent to a method with implicit
>   parameters. Consider first the case of a single parameter with
>   [...] context bounds such as:
>
> ```
> def f[A: U1](params): R = ...
> ```
>
> Then the method definition above is expanded to
>
> ```
> def f[A](params)(implicit v1: U1[A]): R  = ...
> ```
>
> where the `v1` is a fresh name for the newly introduced implicit
>   parameter. This parameter is called evidence parameter.

Here is a [link to FAQ](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html) with more information on the topic.