# Context Bound on a Generic Class Using Implicits

Tags: scala, generics, types, implicit, context-bound

I am learning Scala in order to use it for a project.

One thing I want to get a deeper understanding of is the type system, as it is something I have never used before in my other projects.

Suppose I have set up the following code:

```
// priority implicits
sealed trait Stringifier[T] {
  def stringify(lst: List[T]): String
}

trait Int_Stringifier {
  implicit object IntStringifier extends  Stringifier[Int] {
    def stringify(lst: List[Int]): String = lst.toString()
  }
}

object Double_Stringifier extends Int_Stringifier {
  implicit object DoubleStringifier extends Stringifier[Double] {
    def stringify(lst: List[Double]): String = lst.toString()
  }
}

import Double_Stringifier._

object Example extends App {

  trait Animal[T0] {
    def incrementAge(): Animal[T0]
  }

  case class Food[T0: Stringifier]() {
    def getCalories  = 100
  }

  case class Dog[T0: Stringifier]
  (age: Int = 0, food: Food[T0] = Food()) extends Animal[String] {
    def incrementAge(): Dog[T0] = this.copy(age = age + 1)
  }
}
```

So in the example, there is a type error:

```
ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both object DoubleStringifier in object Double_Stringifier of type Double_Stringifier.DoubleStringifier.type
[error]  and value evidence$2 of type Stringifier[T0]
[error]  match expected type Stringifier[T0]
[error]   (age: Int = 0, food: Food[T0] = Food()) extends Animal[String]
```

Ok fair enough. But if I remove the context bound, this code compiles. I.e. if I change the code  for '''Dog''' to:

```
case class Dog[T0]
  (age: Int = 0, food: Food[T0] = Food()) extends Animal[String] {
    def incrementAge(): Dog[T0] = this.copy(age = age + 1)
  }
```

Now I assumed that this would also not compile, because this type is more generic, so more ambiguous, but it does.

What is going on here? I understand that when I put the context bound, the compiler doesn't know whether it is a double or an int. But why then would an even more generic type compile? Surely if there is no context bound, I could potentially have a Dog[String] etc, which should also confuse the compiler.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds): "A context bound describes an implicit value, instead of view bound's implicit conversion. It is used to declare that for some type A, there is an implicit value of type B[A] available"

Answer (score 2):

> Now I assumed that this would also not compile, because this type is more generic, so more ambiguous, but it does.

The ambiguity was between implicits. Both

```
Double_Stringifier.DoubleStringifier
```

and anonymous evidence of `Dog[T0: Stringifier]` (because `class Dog[T0: Stringifier](...)` is desugared to `class Dog[T0](...)(implicit ev: Stringifier[T0])`) were the candidates.

(`Int_Stringifier#IntStringifier` was irrelevant because it has lower priority).

Now you removed the context bound and only one candidate for implicit parameter in `Food()` remains, so there's no ambiguity. I can't see how the type being more generic is relevant. More generic doesn't mean more ambiguous. Either you have ambiguity between implicits or not.

---

Actually if you remove import but keep context bound the anonymous evidence is not seen in default values. So it counts for ambiguity but doesn't count when is alone :)

Scala 2.13.2, 2.13.3.

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro, really appreciate the guidance as this is I think a pretty challenging area for newcomers. I think I am thinking about this problem the wrong way. When you say "only one candidate", is that the Double_Stringifier you are referring to?

Comment: @finite_diffidence Yes. If you remove the import in the scope where you define `case class Dog` the implicit will not be in the scope.

Comment: @finite_diffidence Actually if you remove import but keep context bound the anonymous evidence is not seen in default values. So it counts for ambiguity but doesn't count when is alone :) Scala 2.13.2.

Comment: @finite_diffidence See also "mistake #2" in "Some Mistakes We Made When Designing Implicits – Martin Odersky" https://youtu.be/1h8xNBykZqM?t=772 (starting at 12:52)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me (and if I'm wrong I'm hoping @DmytroMitin will correct me), the key to understanding this is with the default value supplied for the `food` parameter, which makes `class Dog` both a definition site, requiring an implicit be available at the call site, as well as a call site, requiring an implicit must be in scope at compile time.

The `import` earlier in the code supplies the implicit required for the `Food()` call site, but the `Dog` constructor requires an implicit, placed in `ev`, from its call site. Thus the ambiguity.

Comment: Actually if we remove import but keep context bound the anonymous evidence is not seen in default values. So it counts for ambiguity but doesn't count when is alone :) Scala 2.13.2.

Comment: Right. Without the `import` the `food()` call won't compile (no implicit available), but with the `import` then the resulting `ev` evidence counts as an ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh, so if I follow correctly, do you mean something like this at the call site:

case class Dog[T0]
  (age: Int = 0, food: Food[T0] = Food())(implicit ev: Stringifier[T0]) extends Animal[String] {

Comment: @finite_diffidence; Context bound syntax (`[A:B]`) is syntax sugar. Your `Dog` definition site de-surgars to what you've got there. The call site is wherever a new `Dog` instance is created. But because of the default value for the `food` parameter, the `Dog` definition site is also the `Food()` call site.