# Scala Typing: How to Ensure Numeric Type

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming

I have a small problem in Scala with a typing matter. In Haskell, I can do this:

```
add :: (Num a) => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> (a,a)
```

That way, I can throw into `add` any type that is a numeric and supports `+` etc.
I want the same for a Scala class, like so:

```
case class NumPair[A <: Numeric](x: A, y: A)
```

But that does not seem to work. But due to the Scala Docs, `Numeric[T]` is the only trait that allows for these operations, and seems to be extended by `Int`, `Float` etc.

Any tips?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
case class NumPair[A](x:A, y:A)(implicit num:Numeric[A])
```

The `Numeric` instance itself is not extended by `Int`, `Float`, etc., but it is provided as an implicit object. For a longer explanation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436936/scala-compiler-not-recognizing-a-view-bound/4437336#4437336).

Comment: I am not sure if I should like `implicit`s - they're quite nice if you want to save work, but often they destroy the typing system by obscuring the type inference.

Comment: In which way would implicits obscure type inference? - If you wish, you can make the `Numeric` instance an explicit parameter, but then you would always have to pass it in explicitly, which is really redundant for types like `Int`, `Float`, etc. With implicits, you have the choice of whether or not you'd like to pass it explicitly.