# Generic method with `cannot resolve symbol` errors in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I need to get a generic check method that can be used as follows:

`check[Int](10, 1, 5)` and `check[Double](10.0, 1.0, 5.0)`.

I tried this code:

```
trait RangeChecker {
  def check[T <: AnyVal](value:T, mini:T, maxi:T) : Boolean = {
    (value >= mini && value <= maxi)
  }
}
```

However, I get `Cannot resolve symbol` errors for `>=`, `&&` and `<=`. 
What might be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write

```
def check[T <: AnyVal] ...
```

you're defining the method for **all** the subtypes of `AnyVal`.
However, your implementation uses two methods (`<=` and `>=`) which are available only for a subset of types, namely the ones that support ordering.

So you have to specify that the method applies to **all** types for which an ordering **exists**, or in other words

```
def check[T](value: T, min: T, max: T)(implicit ev: T => Ordered[T]): Boolean =
  value >= min && value <= max
```

This syntax is equivalent to a view bound (`<%`)

```
def check[T <% Ordered[T]](value: T, min: T, max: T): Boolean = ...
```

but, since [view bounds are deprecated](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2909), you should avoid it.

---

Another option is to use `Ordering` in this fashion

```
def check[T](value: T, mini: T, maxi: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Boolean = {
  import ord.mkOrderingOps
  value >= mini && value <= maxi
}
```

where importing `ord.mkOrderingOps` gives you the ability of using the regular `>=` and `<=` methods.

Another equivalent alternative using a context bound directly:

```
def check[T: Ordering](value: T, mini: T, maxi: T): Boolean = {
  val ord = implicitly[Ordering[T]]
  import ord.mkOrderingOps
  value >= mini && value <= maxi
}
```

Comment: @samthebest, thanks for noting `mkOrderingOps`, which is nicer than importing the whole thing.

Comment: Why rollback my edit on the question though - your solution is very neat and general, and so I'm hoping to make it easier for people googling to find your answer.  Your answer is the nicest explanation of Context Bounds and View Bounds on SO - it deserves SEO.

Comment: That edit of yours totally changed the sense of the question. The OP didn't even know about context bounds and view bounds. There's plenty of guides and questions about using traits and context bounds for achieving type classes in scala, so it's not so critical that this pops up. If you feel like, you can always ask a general question on SO and even give a generic answer yourself.

Comment: Fair point. I only just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373070/how-do-i-get-an-instance-of-the-type-class-associated-with-a-context-bound

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
def check[T <% Ordered[T]](value: T, mini: T, maxi: T): Boolean = {
    (value >= mini && value <= maxi)
  }
```

The <= and >= operators are defined as part of the Ordered trait, not AnyVal.

EDIT: see the scala API docs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyVal) and [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordered)

EDIT2: Replaced <: with <%

Comment: Could you include an example of calling this method? I'm getting "type mismatch" errors when I try it with `Int`.

Comment: Oh yikes... I'm getting the same thing. I forgot to try an implementation test before I posted (I assumed it would work, since it compiled *facepalm*). IMO, your answer's a bit more elegant, in any case.

Comment: Looks like it works with a view bound (`<%` instead of `<:`).

Comment: I just finished checking that and was about to comment -- I'll edit the post.

Comment: View bounds are deprecated, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25250693/846273)

Answer (score 3):

`AnyVal`s are not required to support operations like `>=`. That's why it won't work like you tried. Unfortunately, there is no superclass of all the orderable `AnyVal`s.

You should use [`Ordering`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala/math/Ordering.html) instead:

```
def check[T](value: T, low: T, high: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Boolean = {
  ord.gteq(value, low) && ord.lteq(value, high)
}
```

You often won't need to define the type `T` explicitly when you call it, either:

```
scala> check(1, 2, 3)
res0: Boolean = false
scala> check(3, 2, 3.5)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: "numeric": anything can have an ordering, like tuples `check((1,2),(1,1),(2,3))`